# How do I set my Sidebar, Feed and Widgets side to side in my Twitter clone?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, twitter

I am building a twitter clone and the sidebar, feed and widgets are not properly aligned as you can see in the picture. What should I do so that I can realign and put them in correct positions? How do I keep them side to side?
[How the clone looks right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jggru.png)

I will provide my css codes for the app, sidebar, feed and the widgets. Please check where I could’ve gone wrong.
For APP:

```
body {
  –twitter-color: #50b7f5;
  –twitter-background: #e6ecf0;
}

.app {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: 1300px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

For feed (just including the positioning):

```
.feed {
  flex: 0.4;
  border-right: 1px solid var(–twitter-background);
  min-width: fit-content;
  overflow-y: scroll;
```

for sidebar:

```
.sidebar {
  border-right: 1px solid var(–twitter-color);
  flex: 0.25;
  min-width: 250px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

for widgets:

```
.widgets {
  flex: 0.3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this line to your css code:

```
.app {
    flex-direction: row;
   }
```

Here is an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-shockley-b0lyj?file=/styles.css).